# Why there is still a cross oorigin error after setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain

I just run a CORS cross origin demo.The demo is running with node.js. Here is the index.html:

```html
<button>click to cross origin using CROS</button>
<p>hello world </p>
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'http://localhost:3001';    
        xhr.open('PUT',url,true);                
        xhr.send();                       
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {     
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {  
                text.innerHTML = xhr.response;
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Here is the serverRes.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var responsePort = 3001;  
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000'); 
    res.send("Hello world from CROS.");  
});

app.listen(responsePort, function () {
    console.log('cros_responser is listening on port '+ responsePort);
});
```

You can see that I have set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with `http://localhost:3000`,so the response to the preflighted request should actually pass the access control check,which means the request will succeed anyway.But when I go to the port 3000,what I get is:

[image]

But why?Why there is still a cross oorigin error after setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in server side?
Also,I have tried writing:

```js
app.all('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.send("Hello world from CROS.");   
    next(); // pass control to the next handler
});
```

according to [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my). But the error still exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted should work.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var responsePort = 3001;  


app.all("/", function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  next();
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000'); 
    res.send("Hello world from CROS.");  
});

app.listen(responsePort, function () {
    console.log('cros_responser is listening on port '+ responsePort);
});
```

Try hitting this repl instead.

https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/WirelessGentleSigns

Comment: The options request  is passing. You need to handle the PUT request in your code.

Comment: I have handled it (print the data)

Comment: Are you sure? Try hitting the repl again. I have added a PUT route

Comment: And 404 is not related to cors btw :). It should be a problem with the PUT handler you have written in your code and that's not related to the question you have posted

Comment: oh,it works.But i am confused about the code,since here is the put request,could we remove the `app.get()` while keeping the `app.put()`?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, If you don't need a GET handler, you are free to remove it

Comment: No problem. The code you posted was already right. I just proved it works hehe

Answer (score 0):

you also need to allow the http verbs with the header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
```

This answer has a more detailed description:
[Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

Comment: No,it does not work. I changed the code to `app.all('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.send("Hello world from CROS.");   
    next(); 
});`,but nothing changes.Still an error.

Comment: maybe I missed the "OPTIONS" method... I will add it

Comment: did you follow the instruction on the link i posted?

Comment: your comment does not have the OPTIONS method... look at the updated answer

Comment: I will try it.But my request is PUT,why need to set Access-Control-Allow-Methods including OPTIONS?

Comment: it is part of CORS, if you look at the request of the error you posted, it happens on the OPTIONS call, which is the normal behavior